# Consuming IIS hosted WCF via jQuery: IIS Error 400.0

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, wcf

I am writing a jQuery/Ajax implementation to consume IIS hosted WCF. 
This jquery code is in a page on same server as the WCF. 
Below is that code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://xxx.yyy.com/_vti_bin/zzz_Service/mDart4Service.svc/StatusAsOn",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server 
            dataType: "jsonp", //Expected data format from server                       

            success: function (xml) {
                alert("1");
                alert(xml);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Some Error');
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(xhr.error);
            }
        });
    });
```

All web resources that I uses more or less same code to comsume it. But same is not working in my case. It always goes to error function. Checked on Fiddler / IISLogs it says 400.0 error code (Bad Syntax). 
Not sure why this is not working for me !

P.S. Also when I try to browse the WCF service on (https://xxx.yyy.com/_vti_bin/zzz_Service/mDart4Service.svc/StatusAsOn) on browser, error code is same.

Comment: Is it a REST service?
Can you please provide what your service interface looks like?

Comment: 400.0 error code  means bad request .check you request data format